# Something is wrong with GoogleAPI.orgUnits.get()

Tags: google-api

I have code that has been working flawlessly for a very long time.  I was working on an issue with a customer and found that my unit tests are no longer working either (I haven't adjusted this code for a while so the tests haven't been run).

Try the code here:
[Google's Reference for Orgunits.get (and online trial of api)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/get)

So I went to the directory API page to try it directly.  I went to the link above and entered the customer ID for my test environment and then '/AllUsers' in the orgUnitPath (this container does exist in the google domain I'm working with) and it came back with a red 404; no other information. I also tried / as well but that didn't work either. This WAS working, but I don't know how long it's been inop.

I can insert OU's ok though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to try using the playground. It works for me there. The link is this one https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground.

The only scope you will need is this: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit` and you will have to enter it manually.

Exchange the code for a token then make a get to the following url: `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/orgunits/`

It should give you a list of the org units. Oh, by the way, the "Try It" section of the developer's documentation seems to be buggy with this. I hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't know this existed! I've been using the samples on their dev site.  This does work. Thanks!